# Should i Include system as an actor in my use case diagram?

Tags: uml, agile, use-case, use-case-diagram

[image: it add a rating use case diagram for an app am working on]

Should I Include the system as an actor in my use case diagram?

I am working on an app which have added a rating for an institute here is the use case diagram I made, should there be a system as an actor in this use case diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To indicate the (operating) system as a secondary actor has no plus value,  better to not do then.

There are several other problems in your diagram :

- use verb to name your UC, *username, password, dashboard* and *institution* are wrong name
- the inheritances are invalid
- I cannot understand your includes because the included UC are wrongly named
- for several people *login* does not have enough added value to appear, if you want it note it is a precondition of the other UCs

Comment: Thanks, a lot man it helps me and I will surely change the names of use cases

Comment: Should I always use verbs for use cases?

Comment: @Faseeh yes UC use verb, an UC is not a 'data', an UC cannot inherits an actor

Comment: Sure got ur point these were provided to me by a team member and I had to finalize these.

Comment: Is this condition is the same for Activity, Sequence, and collaboration diagrams of UML?

Comment: @Faseeh what you mean the same ?

Comment: let me show u the other diagrams too

Comment: @Faseeh open new questions, a question must not be multiple

Comment: Here is the activity Diagram Link

https://ibb.co/GkWqSPh

Here is the Sequence Diagram

https://ibb.co/GsLQDDg


Here is the Collaboration Diagram


https://ibb.co/F56q6zr

Comment: okay opening other questions

Comment: I have to wait for like 90 minutes for opening a single new question it would be helpful if u can assist me here.

Comment: @Faseeh I did not know that limitation exist. That let you time to look at UML documentation/tutorial ;-) For instance in a seq diagram the top lifeline elements are instance of classes, *login* cannot be nor *add rating* etc. The UC describe *what* the system does, the other diagrams *how* the system does / is implemented, you cannot reuse the UC as you do

Comment: sure man, I will look into UML documentation